# Name Bot is not defined in cicle while

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a cicle while inside a class in order to create a "infinite" loop, when i associate "test" istance to "print" method, error "name 'bot' is not defined" appear.
How i could fix it?

here the code:

```
class bot:

  while(1):
    test = bot()
    def print():
        print = "Hello"
        return print
    test = bot()
    print(test.print())
```

thanks you

Comment: don't call `bot()` inside class `bot`

Comment: class name becomes available after its whole content is parsed. Wrap the code inside a method in the class, that should help. Also try not override existing function names, you might have a hard time - `print` is an existing function already.